# How to make a fuzzy filter in Power Query according to a list

Tags: excel, powerquery

I want to filter a Power Query table according to another list:

The fact table is:

```
Location    Name

MEL/1F/101  zmel
SHA         zsha
BKK/2F      zbkk
SGN         zsgn
```

And the lookup list is

{"BKK","SHA"}

The result I want is

```
Location    Name

SHA         zsha
BKK/2F      zbkk
```

Now I use

```
l={"SHA","BKK"},
b=Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Column1", each List.Contains(l,[location]))
```

but the BKK/2F is omitted, only SHA shows.

Does any one knows to correct this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new column using conditional Column by referencing to the table column that contains **SHA & BKK**. Replace the `Column Name` to your column.

You can use `fill down` function if you want to get rid of the nulls.

**Update**

For your case you might want to use the operator `begins with` since your BKK has extra text behind

[image]